# On ProtocolException custom IClientMessageInspector is not called

Tags: wcf, exception, logging

I use `IClientMessageInspector` at a client side to log raw responses received from the server side. However as soon as at the server side happens unexpected situation ending in 500 Internal error my custom class implementing `IClientMessageInspector` is not being called. Instead `ProtocolException` is being thrown.

Obviously, it is clear that `IClientMessageInspector` operates Messages and since parsing failed there is no Messages to inspect. Therefore, my question is

Is it possible get access to original raw response even though it is erroneous/bad-formed/etc by other means than `IClientMessageInspector`?

Comment: Hello, did you ever find a solution to your problem?  I am facing something similar.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately there is no any simple approach to do this.

Comment: I had to go one level up and catch all the `CommunicationException`-related errors on a proxy level...